# PJAX, обновить 2 блока, без дополнительного события pjax:success

Tags: php, jquery, pjax

Нужно обновить 2 блока. Если вешать на событие pjax:success еще один запрос, получается 2 запроса на сервер. Возможно, кто либо знает, как грамотно поступить ?

```
  $('body').pjax('a[data-pjax]', '.content', {fragment: '.content', type: 'post', scrollTo: 0, timeout: 2000,});

  $('body')
    .on('submit', 'form[data-pjax]', function(event) {
      $.pjax.submit(event, '.content', {fragment: '.content', type: 'post', scrollTo: 0, timeout: 2000,});
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Вариант 1.** Использовать обычный ajax

```
$.ajax({
    'success': function(data){
        var targets = [
            '#container1',
            '#container2'
        ];
        $.each(targets, function (ind, t) {
            $(t).html($(data).find(t).html());
        });
    }
});
```

**Вариант 2.** Использовать pjax, но будет 2 запроса

```
$.pjax.reload({container: "#container1", async:false});
$.pjax.reload({container: "#container2", async:false});
```

P.S. К [разработчикам Pjax](https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=multiple+containers) обращаются с 2012г с просьбой сделать 1 запросом, делать не планируют